# Есть ли в питоне функция, которая сможет среди векторов(массивов) найти линейную зависимость

Tags: python, python-3.x

`⊕` - Исключа́ющее «или»

`ei ⊕ .... ⊕ ek = 0`

массивы:

> e1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
>
> e2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
>
> e3 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
>
> e4 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>
> e5 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>
> e6 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
>
> e7 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>
> e8 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

В данном примере ответ вот такой: `e1⊕e3⊕e6⊕e8 = 0`

почему именно `e1, e3, e6, e8` - **результат равен 0, если нет операндов, равных 1, либо их чётное количество.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю алгоритм выйдет большой и затратный для этого, если нет функции

Comment: Задача достаточно специфичная, так что если и существует уже написанная функция, то валяется она в богом забытом пакете где-то на гитхабе. Кажется, гораздо проще написать самому, чем найти

Comment: @EzikBro пытаюсь написать сам, честно трудновато, сложно

Comment: Ну я не нашел никакого способа, кроме полного перебора по маске.

Comment: За кубическое время гауссовым исключением решается, в точности как обычная система линейных уравнений.